# Grepping a batch ping

Tags: batch-file, cmd, grep, ping, findstr

Looking for a better way to do this rather than the "by-hand" method I'm used to, because it's a process I have to go through fairly regularly.

I have a range of IPs to ping, from `10.0.1.15` to `10.0.50.15`. The third octet refers to a physical location and the last octet refers to a device at that location. I need to see which locations DO NOT have that device hooked up to the network.

My current solution is:

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,50) DO ping -n 1 10.0.%i.15 >> C:\path\to\output\file.txt
```

This gives me output like

```
Pinging 10.0.1.15 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.1.15: bytes=32 time=68ms TTL=255

Ping statistics for 10.0.1.15:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 68ms, Maximum = 68ms, Average = 68ms

Pinging 10.0.2.15 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.0.2.15:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
...
```

I'd prefer output more like:

```
2
...
```

But honestly anything human-readable is fine -- this isn't being piped anywhere.

In this case, location 1 has the device present, but location 2 does not.

Currently the best solution I have for doing this is to look through that file by hand and keep track. I could hack something together in Python but it sounds like more trouble than it's worth. I know that `grep` has some ability to show context, but I'm on Windows and don't have access to anything but the basic NT CLI tools.

Is there some way to leverage `findstr` (or etc) to get a more easily human-readable output? Is there some better method in e.g. Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You can use `find` (or `findstr` if you prefer) to test for the existence of <strike>"TTL"</strike> **"TTL="** (edit: See MC ND's comment below) and use the resulting ERRORLEVEL to determine success or fail.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /L %%I in (1,1,50) do (
    ping -n 1 10.0.%%I.15 | find /i "TTL=" >NUL && (
        echo 10.0.%%I.15: Online
    ) || (
        echo 10.0.%%I.15: OFFLINE
    )
)
```

[See this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php) for more info on conditional execution (the `&&` and `||` stuff).  `find` sets `ERRORLEVEL` to 0 on success, or 1 on fail.  If you want the results logged to a txt file rather than the console, just wrap the whole thing in another parenthetical code block like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "logfile=C:\path\to\output\file.txt"

>> "%logfile%" (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,50) do (
        ping -n 1 10.0.%%I.15 | find /i "TTL=" >NUL && (
            echo 10.0.%%I.15: Online
        ) || (
            echo 10.0.%%I.15: OFFLINE
        )
    )
)

type "%logfile%"
```

Comment: So to list only those locations whose tests fail would be something like `ping -n 1 10.0.%%I.15 | find /i "TTL" >NUL || echo something indicating location number goes here`? Or do I have to indicate a "pass" test before I can indicate a "fail" test?

Comment: You can indicate `|| fail` without having to do anything for pass if you wish.

Comment: A `TTL expired` error also includes the `TTL` string. It is better to test for the presence of `TTL=`

Comment: @AdamSmith See MC ND's comment and my edited answer.